# parsing/scanning/tokenizing "raw XML"

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have an application where I need to parse or tokenize XML **and** preserve the raw text (e.g. don't parse entities, don't convert whitespace in attributes, keep attribute order, etc.) in a Java program.

I've spent several hours today trying to use StAX, SAX, XSLT, TagSoup, etc. before realizing that none of them do this. I can't afford to spend much more time attacking this problem, and parsing the text manually seems highly nontrivial. Is there any Java library that can help me tokenize the XML?

**edit:** why am I doing this? -- I have a large XML file that I want to make a small number of localized changes programmatically, that need to be reviewed. It is highly valuable to be able to use a diff tool. If the parser/filter normalizes the XML, then all I see is "red ink" in the diff tool. The application that produces the XML in the first place isn't something that I can easily have changed to produce "canonical XML", if there is such a thing.

Comment: Why do you need to preserve the raw text?

Comment: The raw text may have newlines etc in it that he wants to keep. attribute order and the like might be important for his use.

Comment: According to the XML spec, any non-markup characters including whitespace such as newlines are passed to the application: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space

Comment: SAX does preserve newlines in characters & CDATA. It does not preserve newlines in attributes.

Comment: ...and quite bluntly, having all these great parsing tools that do SAX, StAX, etc. but don't expose the intermediate parsing/tokenizing steps, feels like having a series of magic boxes that turn sewage in to wine, when what I want is the grape juice.

Comment: If you want to use a diff tool I would try to "normalize" both files before using the tool. In that way you see the real changes and not only the formatting changes

Comment: What if you were to make a duplicate copy of the XML?  Use SAX or whatever to parse the DOM, save the node info along with your desired edits somewhere, then use that info to edit the "plain-text" XML using some grep facility to search-and-replace?

I guess you could even add custom "edithere" kind of attributes on the first pass, then on the second pass use a plain text parser to search and replace...

To be honest I have no idea if that will really work - anyway, you know your requirements better than me...

Comment: @weiji: yes, something along those lines occurred to me, but the search and replace step is difficult (can't guarantee I can find the right spot in the xml file). thanks though!

Comment: @Jason S wow that's the issue, ability to diff? Run the StAX processor once in "pass-through" mode to normalize it; then run it again with the programming logic. Then diff the outputs!

Comment: As other have said you are ask something of XML that it was not designed to provide.  You therefore need to expand the scope of possible solutions.  What are the nature of the changes your need to make ?  Are they repetitive, all Xs into Zs but simple.  Are they conditional Add 1 to all Ns in all Xs.  Is there any reason you cannot load the document into a word processor and just use search and replace, or a programmers editor and use built macro features.  Can you use GREP/SED/AWK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have to generate your own grammar.

Some links:

- [Parsing XML with ANTLR Tutorial](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Parsing+XML)
- [ANTXR](http://javadude.com/tools/antxr/index.html)
- [XPA](http://xpa.sourceforge.net/)
- http://www.google.com/search?q=antlr+xml

Comment: I think you might be right, and it's painful. I don't know how to use ANTLR, and I can't even find a machine-readable BNF for XML. W3C has http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/ but the BNF is interspersed with text. >:(

Comment: It was painful, but as far as I can tell, I got it done OK, and in the future I can use the code I wrote.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. For anyone else needing to extract BNF from the XML spec, it can be scraped from the XML version (currently at http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/REC-xml11-20060816.xml). Search for <scrap lang="ebnf"> elements

Comment: Please be a good citizen and elaborate on how just solved it so that everybody can learn from your experience.

Comment: @Martin: I used "pure Java", no libraries, didn't use BNF, and wrote a tokenizer to parse XML in a way that preserves the original text for each element.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any XML parser will do what you want. Why ? For instance, the XML spec doesn't enforce attribute ordering. I think you're going to have to parse it yourself, and that is non-trivial.

Why do you have to do this ? I'm guessing you have some client 'XML' that enforces or relies on non-standard construction. In that case I'd push back and get that fixed, rather than jump through numerous fixes to try and accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand what it is you are trying to do. Have you tried using CDATA regions for the parts of the document you don't want the parser to touch?

Also relying on attribute order is *not* a good idea - if I remember the XML standard correctly then order is never to be expected.

It sounds like you are dealing with some malformed XML and that it would be easier to first turn it into proper XML.